# Peut-on utiliser le présent du subjonctif en concordance avec le futur ?

Tags: grammaire, temps-grammatical, subjonctif, concordance-des-temps

Peut-on dire « J'y réfléchirai avant que je prenne le cours » ? Faut-il utiliser une concordance des temps dans *je prenne* si j'utilise le futur dans la proposition principale ?

Peut-on dire aussi :

> J'y réfléchirai *avant que je m'inscrive au cours*.
>   *Il me faut réfléchir* avant que je prenne le cours.
>   *Je dois réfléchir* avant que je prenne le cours.

Comment: *Il me faut réfléchir*, trop affreux ?! Je ne suis pas de cet avis. Un peu trop littéraire pour certains contextes, certainement, mais aussi juste qu'élégant.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Pardon, mal je m'exprimais : *il me faut réfléchir avant que je prenne le cours* trop affreux. Les autres associations, pas des plus heureuses, mais peut-être acceptables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je ne suis pas entièrement certain des détails, mais je crois que l'on doit obligatoirement utiliser une formule infinitive dans ce genre de construction si le sujet des deux verbes est le même:

> J'y réfléchirai *avant de prendre le cours*.
>   J'y réfléchirai *avant de m'inscrire au cours*.

Les trois formules, « *j'y réfléchirai* », « *il me faut (y) réfléchir* », « *je dois (y) réfléchir avant de* », sont toutes possibles, mais *Il me faut* est plutôt littéraire, donc à garder pour les situations requérant un langage relevé. Ce n'est pas un usage de tous les jours.

Si ce n'étais de ce problème, le subjonctif serait approprié (il est obligatoire, si ma mémoire est bonne, après *avant que*).

Comment: Tu as peut-être raison ; cette règle ne me dit rien du tout, à moi ça me semble très maladroit mais correct. +1, mais j'aimerais bien voir une autorité soutenir ça, ou bien une nuance sur *obligatoirement*.

Comment: Vraiment? Pour moi ° *J'y réfléchirai avant que je prenne le cours* est aussi incorrect que le serait ° *Je veux que je parte*, mais si le sujet de la subordonnée diffère (*...qu'il ne prenne le cours/qu'il parte*), c'est parfaitement naturel. Autrement dit, *avant que* requiert bel et bien le subjonctif, mais **cette phrase ne s'écrira pas normalement avec cette locution subjonctive.**

Comment: C'est sûr qu'avec des exemples aussi percutants… Mais quand même : « *Avant que je n'y aille, j'aimerais m'entretenir avec toi.* », ça serait faux ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas idéal (je favoriserait quand même *J'aimerais m'entretenir avec toi avant d'y aller.*), mais ça sonne bien mieux que *Avant d'y aller, j'aimerais...* (mais c'est p-ê parce que cette phrase me donner envie d'utiliser *partir* à la place.).

Comment: L'erreur provient du JE + JE.  Il y réfléchira avant que je dise ce que pense. J'y réfléchirai avant qu'il parte. ***Il faut deux sujets différents*** dans le propositions pour le subjonctif: J'y réfléchirai avant que je pars. Pas de subjonctif....

Answer (score 5):

Oui, on utilise bien le présent du subjonctif en concordance avec le futur. La phrase choque, comme l'a déjà [remarqué Circeus](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5750/peut-on-utiliser-le-present-du-subjonctif-en-concordance-avec-le-futur/5751#5751), parce qu'on ne répète pas le sujet lorsqu'il est le même que dans la phrase principale, [on utilise l'infinitif présent à la place](http://www.pomme.ualberta.ca/pomme/FMPro?-DB=R.FP5&-Format=regle_frame.htm&-lay=default&-op=eq&ID=722&-find), avec la préposition correspondant à la conjonction de subordination (*avant que* → *avant de*).

> J'y réfléchirai avant de m'inscrire au cours.

Si on change de sujet, c'est bien le subjonctif présent qui s'impose.

> J'y réfléchirai avant que tu m'inscrives au cours.

Comment: Ah ha ! En fait, le problème, c'est la répétition du sujet, pas l'accord du verbe. La réponse à la question serait donc « Oui au titre. Non on ne peut pas dire …, mais pour une autre raison que la question ».